# Boot Ubuntu without X

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, xorg

After installing Ubuntu Server 9.10, I couldn't get X to work, so I installed `xfce-desktop` from apt-get, hoping it would fix the problem (it didn't, but I got it working later).

I just rebooted my computer for the first time since then, and got an Xubuntu login screen. How can I disable this, and have it boot up into text mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Temporary way. You can hold Shift at boot time; after Grub menu will be displayed, select an item that ends with '(recovery mode)' and press Enter. Your machine will be booted in single-user console mode.
2. Permanent way. Following [this Ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1322949), edit `/etc/init/gdm.conf` and comment out full `start on` directive (attention: it is spreaded across multiple lines). After that you should be able to start Xorg with `start gdm` command under `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Change /etc/inittab to boot to level 2 not 5. If inittab is missing, create it. It is read by the /etc/event.d/rc-default script, and you might want to look at that. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=620327

Comment: Will not work in 9.10 because of migration from sysvinit to upstart.